# Drawing string at the center of arc

Tags: java

I have pie chart to display the rate of sales through out the year,now i want to draw a string  at the center of each arc respectively,to specify the month in my pie chart
this is how my code looks like

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class TopSectionPanel extends JPanel {

double[] sales = {4000, 3000, 2000, 6000 , 10000 , 2500, 
                  3400 , 8700 , 6734 , 1200 , 4500 , 6700};
double[] angle = new double[sales.length];
Color[] color  = {Color.RED, Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.DARK_GRAY, Color.GREEN,
                  Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Color.MAGENTA, Color.ORANGE, Color.PINK, Color.WHITE,
                  Color.YELLOW, Color.GRAY};
double sum     = 0;

/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
public TopSectionPanel() {
    setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400 , 400));

    for(int l = 0 ; l < sales.length ; l++) 
        sum += sales[l];

    for(int i = 0 ; i < angle.length ; i++)
        angle[i] = sales[i] / sum * 360;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int radius;

    // calculations to fit the circle in exact center
    if(getHeight() < getWidth())
        radius = (int) ((getHeight() / 2.) * 0.8) ;
    else
        radius = (int) ((getWidth() / 2.) * 0.8) ;

    int diameter = radius * 2;
    int x = (int)(getWidth() / 2) - radius;
    int y = (int)(getHeight() / 2) - radius;


    double a = 0;
    for( int i = 0 ; i < angle.length ; i++ ) {
        g.setColor(color[i]);
        g.fillArc(x, y, diameter, diameter, (int)a, (int)angle[i]);
        a = a + angle[i];
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing minor details of the requirements such as distance from the arc or font or size I can only produce a raw sketch, using some elementary geometry. Add this after the loop drawing the pie chart.

```
int mx = x + radius;
int my = y + radius;
double b = 0;
int rad = (int)(radius*1.20);
for( int i = 0 ; i < angle.length ; i++ ) {
    b += angle[i]/2;
    double brad = b*Math.PI/180.0;
    int ix = (int)(rad*Math.cos(brad));
    int iy = (int)(rad*Math.sin(brad));
    g.drawString( Integer.toString(i+1), mx+ix, my-iy );
    b += angle[i]/2;
}
```

Note that the computed coordinates are the point on the baseline where the text starts. If you really want to center the text around this point you'll have to compute the bounding box for the text and modify the coordinates by these small amounts in x- and y-direction.

Comment: I get the idea , appreciate it :)

Comment: @UsmanNaseer As I review this: a constant added to the radius might be better than that factor 1.20. Depends on whether and how you intend to scale the pie.

Comment: Yeah , now it looks even better